# Inserting coloured text in a buffer

Tags: buffers, faces, font-lock

I want to insert with colour properties. But when I try inserting in a new buffer, the colours get removed.

```
(defun ticker-second (lampkl)
  "TODO."

  (interactive)

  (cond
   ((eq 'green lampkl)
       (insert (propertize "G"
                 'font-lock-face '(:background "green"
                                   :foreground "black"))))
   ((eq 'blue lampkl)
       (insert (propertize "B"
                 'font-lock-face '(:background "#8A8AFF"
                                   :foreground "black")))))
  (insert "_"))


(defun fire-clock (bufrn)
  "TODO."
  (interactive)

  (let ( (ss (nth 0 (decode-time)))    ; seconds
         (mm (nth 1 (decode-time)))    ; minutes
         (hh (nth 2 (decode-time))) )  ; hours

    (message "hh: %d" hh)
    (message "mm: %d" mm)
    (message "ss: %d" ss)

    (goto-char (point-min))

    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create bufrn)

      (dotimes (i (/ ss 5))
        (ticker-second 'green))
      (dotimes (i (% ss 5))
        (ticker-second 'blue)))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer you create is in `fundamental-mode`.  If you fire `text-mode` in that buffer, the text properties show up and you get coloured letters.

Comment: I get color in `fundamental-mode` as well. I believe what matters is whether your have `font-lock` universally enabled: after all, it's the `font-lock-face` that's propertized.

Comment: Odd: I have `(global-font-lock-mode)` in my init and the variable `global-font-lock-mode` reports that it is `t`.  But I just found out that it is not turned on in `fundamental-mode` buffers for me.  I wonder why?

Comment: You are absolutely right.  Perhaps a bug report would be appropriate?